# create-react-app. dont reload after save App.js

Tags: create-react-app

The page is not refreshed when App.js saved.

> ```
> Compiled successfully!
>
> You can now view my-app in the browser.
>
>   Local:            http://localhost:3000        
>   On Your Network:  http://172.17.206.116:3000   
>
> Note that the development build is not optimized.
> To create a production build, use npm run build.
> ```
>
> node -v  v14.17.0
>
> npm -v 6.14.13

windows 10

Comment: Did you run it with "npm run start"?

Comment: yes, i did "npm start" and also i did "npm run start"